# Alpha tested text rendering of signed distance field creates wiggly edges

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, distance, text-rendering

I am trying to render the text in my application using a glyph atlas represented as a signed distance field texture, which means a texture which stores the distance to the nearest outline in each pixel.
This distance field texture is generated from the original binary glyph atlas texture (0 - outside of glyph outline, 1 - inside glyph outline) with this algorithm, which is searching an incremental radius around every pixel in the texture until a pixel with the opposite state is found, then stores the distance at which that pixel was found. Later, all distances are mapped between 0 and 1.

```
//set size of signed distance field atlas
atlas.width = binaryAtlasWidth* pDistanceFieldResolution;
atlas.height = binaryAtlasHeight * pDistanceFieldResolution;

const unsigned int atlasPixelCount = (atlas.width * atlas.height);
atlas.buffer.resize(atlasPixelCount);

//temporary buffer for the distances of each pixel
std::vector<float> unmappedBuffer;
unmappedBuffer.resize(atlasPixelCount);
//support multisampling
unsigned int samplesPerOutPixel = ceil(1.0 / pDistanceFieldResolution);

//for mapping the values between 0 and 1 later
float maxDistance = 0.0;
float minDistance = 0.0;

for (unsigned int outPixel = 0; outPixel < atlasPixelCount; ++outPixel) {
    //coordinate of the input sample
    unsigned int outPixelX = outPixel%atlas.width;
    unsigned int outPixelY = outPixel/atlas.width;

    float distanceSum = 0.0f;

    for (unsigned int sampleY = 0; sampleY < samplesPerOutPixel; ++sampleY) {
        for (unsigned int sampleX = 0; sampleX < samplesPerOutPixel; ++sampleX) {

            glm::uvec2 sampleCoord = glm::uvec2(outPixelX * samplesPerOutPixel+ sampleX, outPixelY * samplesPerOutPixel+ sampleY);
            unsigned int samplePos = sampleCoord.x + sampleCoord.y*binaryAtlasWidth;
            unsigned char sampleVal = buffer[samplePos];
            //inital distance is maximum search radius(outside of glyph)
            float dist = spread;
            int found = 0;
            unsigned int rad = 0;
            while(!found && (rad*(!sampleVal)) < spread_pixels) {
                //if sampleVal is 1(inside), search until found
                float radius = (float)rad + 1.0f;
                unsigned int compareCount = round(2.0f*radius*M_PI);
                float step = 1.0 / (float)compareCount;

                for (unsigned int t = 0; t < compareCount && !found; ++t) {
                    float theta = step*(float)t*360.0f;
                    glm::vec2 compareLocalCoord = glm::vec2(std::cos(theta), std::sin(theta))*radius;
                    glm::uvec2 compareCoord = sampleCoord + glm::uvec2(compareLocalCoord);
                    int comparePos = compareCoord.x + compareCoord.y*binaryAtlasWidth;
                    if (compareCoord.x >= 0 && compareCoord.x < binaryAtlasWidth&& compareCoord.y >= 0 && compareCoord.y < binaryAtlasHeight) {

                        unsigned char compareVal = buffer[comparePos];
                        if (compareVal != sampleVal ) {
                            float distance = sqrt(pow(compareLocalCoord.x, 2) + pow(compareLocalCoord.y, 2));
                            found = 1;
                            dist = std::min(distance * (1 - (sampleVal * 2)) , dist) ;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++rad;
            }
            distanceSum += dist;
        }
    }

    float avgDistance = distanceSum / (float)(samplesPerOutPixel*samplesPerOutPixel);
    printf("pixel  %i  of  %i  has  %f  distance\n", outPixel, atlasPixelCount, avgDistance);
    unmappedBuffer[outPixel] = avgDistance;
    maxDistance = std::max(maxDistance, avgDistance);
    minDistance = std::min(minDistance, avgDistance);
}
minDistance *= -1.0;
float diff = maxDistance + minDistance;

//map all values between 0 and 255
for(unsigned int p = 0; p < atlasPixelCount; ++p) {
    float toMap = unmappedBuffer[p];
    float mappedDistance = 1.0f - (toMap + minDistance) / diff;
    atlas.buffer[p] = mappedDistance * 255;
}
```

this algorithm creates these results:

266 x 183 input texture

[image]

SDF result without downsampling (still 266 x 183)

[image]

SDF result with downsampling (106 x 73)

[image]

Render results with alpha testing on(pass when alpha is greater than 0.5):

no downsampling, nearest filtering

[image]

downsampled, nearest filtering

[image]

no downsampling, linear filtering

[image]
[image]

downsampled, linear filtering

[image]
[image]

I mean, I am getting there, but actually I expected accurate edges as shown in [valves paper](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf). What am i missing for accurate edges?

PS: my fragment shader currently only uses the distance texture value as an alpha value. (`color = vec4(1, 1, 1, distance);`)

Comment: They use much higher downsampling ratios, and your distance transform doesn't look accurate enough. See https://cs.brown.edu/~pff/dt/ for a fast and accurate distance transform algorithm.

Comment: I would just like to thank you for this great resource here!